# Check list of specific users for two Active Directory Groups in Common

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a couple powershell scripts that do parts of what I need separately. But don't know how to combine into one script. I want to limit the result list to check ONLY the list of users I provide.

So I want to know --
Is User1 in both Group1 AND Group2?
Is User2 in both Group1 and Group2?
Is User3 in both Group1 and Group3?
etc..

Here are my separate scripts. I can also run the first once, then get a new list, and run it against group two. But would like to have one script if possible.

First script checks list and returns list included in group using a Get-Content command and ForEach.

```
$users = Get-Content C:\temp\user_list.txt
$group = "group1"
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty samaccountname
ForEach ($user in $users) {
    If ($members -contains $user) {
      Write-Host "$user"
 }
 }
```

Second gets list of members from one Group1, then compares each user to Group2, returning positives.

```
#checks two specified groups against each other and returns who is in both lists
# Get the members of Group1
$group1 = get-adgroupmember "group1";
 
# Get the members of Group2
$group2 = get-adgroupmember "group2";
 
  
# Loop through each user in Group1
foreach ($group1user in $group1){
 
    # For each user in Group1, loop through every user in Group2 looking for a match
    foreach ($group2user in $group2){
 
        # If a match is found
        if ($group1user.samaccountname -eq $group2user.samaccountname) {
            write-host $group1user.samaccountname;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to check only the users in user_list.txt for if each user is in both group1 and group2? I am assuming user_list.txt contains samAccountName. Is it always exactly 2 groups you're checking?

Comment: Joshua -- yes, all correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions here that there's always a group1/group2 and that user_list contains a list of user samaccountnames.

Instead of nested foreach loops based on the groups in your second code block, you might consider storing the group membership lists in variables like you did in your first code block:

```
$group1Members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "group1" -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty samaccountname
$group2Members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "group2" -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty samaccountname
```

Then you could loop through your desired list of users once, leveraging the Contains method, like so:

```
foreach($user in $users) {
    if($group1Members.contains($user) -and $group2Members.contains($user)) {
        # the user is in both groups
        Write-Output $user
    }
}
```

**NOTE: There is a caveat - this assumes the capitalization of a user's samAccountName is an exact match. While string comparison is case-insensitive by default in PowerShell, when using Contains, this is not the case**

One unrelated tip - you'll notice I used Write-Output - this is generally preferred to Write-Host as it can be captured to a variable or outputted to a file, etc, whereas Write-Host can't.

Comment: Joshua - thanks for the example code and great insights. I played around a bit and found case sensitivity in my imported list had an effect on results. I added to first section of code:

$users = Get-Content C:\temp\user_list.txt

If I had "jdoe" in my list (and is present in both groups) it did not get written to the output. But if it was "JDoe" then it would. I will have to find a way to get my needed lists with expected caps/lowercase. But other than that, it looks good. Thanks again.

As a trivial note, I had to add one missing closing parenthesis to the second block.

Comment: Hmm....for the most part I can make my list(s) conform with minimal effort, however, sometimes there are random caps in the samaccountname -- eg. an account may be JDoeSmith (instead of JDoesmith) Do you know of a way to modify the contains to be case-insensitive?

Comment: @DavidBorough Change the `.contains($user)` method (which is Case-sensitive) into `-contains $user`

Comment: Joshua and Theo, thanks -- that worked! Would upvote but I guess I still need some rep on this account :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped, and hey, I've now learned that -contains is not case sensitive :) I've fixed the missing paren in my example.